# Menubar on website homepage changing colors in Firefox when scrolled

Tags: html, css, firefox

Let me start off by saying I'm not the most advanced programmer - at all. I have been put in charge of placing social media icons in the top right corner of our product line pages. I don't have the issue on my monitor, but apparently when you open up our URL in Firefox, and scroll up and down, the menu bar and background of the page shifts from white to grey. It doesn't seem to have this problem in Chrome. Any help is much appreciated!

I have created the following div in the CSS portion:

```
.Social {
    width: 6%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -7.5em;
    left: 87%;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #000;

}
```

Additionally, I have implemented the following HTML

```
<div class="fullscreen">
<div class="Social"> 

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/alliedsystemscompany" target="_blank"><img src="images/FacebookSocialIcon.fw.png" width="30px"></a>
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/allied-systems" target="_blank"><img src="images/LinkedInSocialIcon.fw.png" width="30px"></a>

</div>
```

The website URL is http://www.alliedsystems.com/home.htm

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your bug, try again, it seems work as expected. Tested on Firefox 39

Comment: Hello Connor, Welcome to Stack Overflow! I am not getting this issue on Mozilla Firefox (39).